# Entity framework GetDatabaseValues() throw NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, dbcontext, entity-framework-4.3

Object code :

```
public class ParticipatingService
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OptimisticVersion { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Receiver site")]
    public int? TargetSiteId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Receiver site")]
    public virtual Hospital TargetSite { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Provider site")]
    public int? SourceSiteId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Provider site")]
    public virtual Hospital SourceSite { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Provider person")]
    public int? SourcePersonId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Provider person")]
    public virtual Person SourcePerson { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Study")]
    public int StudyId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Study")]
    public virtual Study Study { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Start date")]
    public virtual PartialDate StartDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("End date")]
    public virtual PartialDate EndDate { get; set; }

    public int? RegInvestigatorFormId { get; set; }
    public PartialDate AuthorizationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsNationalCoordinator { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Role")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Role")]
    public virtual ParticipatingServiceCLI Role { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Affiliation type")]
    public int? AffiliationId { get; set; }
    public virtual AffiliationCLI Affiliation { get; set; }

    public bool IsFromActivePersonSite
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (PersonSite personSite in SourcePerson.PersonSites.ToList().OrderByDescending(ps => ps.StartDate.Date))
            {
                if (personSite.SiteId == SourceSiteId)
                {
                    return personSite.IsActive();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsFromSecondarySite
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (PersonSite personSite in SourcePerson.PersonSites.ToList().OrderByDescending(ps => ps.StartDate.Date))
            {
                if (personSite.SiteId == SourceSiteId)
                {
                    return personSite.RelationType.StringId.Equals("Secondary");
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool IsActive()
    {
        return !this.IsDeleted && this.SourcePerson != null && this.Study != null && this.TargetSite != null && this.SourcePerson.IsActive() && this.TargetSite.IsActive() && (this.EndDate == null || this.EndDate.Date == null || this.EndDate.Date > DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Repository code :

```
public virtual T Update(T obj)
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<T> dbEntry = this.Context.Entry<T>(obj);
        System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbPropertyValues x = dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues();
        int optimisticValue = x.GetValue<int>("OptimisticVersion");
        if ((int)this.Context.Entry<T>(obj).GetDatabaseValues()["OptimisticVersion"] == obj.OptimisticVersion)
        {
            obj.OptimisticVersion++;
            obj.LastModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
            this.Context.Entry<T>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            this.Context.SaveChanges();
            return obj;
        }
        throw new DBConcurrencyException("The selected item is obsolete !");
    }
```

The problem :

I'm using generic managers and generic repositories with CRUD operations (DRY).
The problem is that when trying to save an object (only 1 type of the solution cause that problem), it works well the first time it is updated. Then trying to update the same object again cause a `NullReferenceException` on the `GetDatabaseValues()`.
I've tried to split the following line :

```
(int)this.Context.Entry<T>(obj).GetDatabaseValues()["OptimisticVersion"] == obj.OptimisticVersion
```

into multiple lines :

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<T> dbEntry = this.Context.Entry<T>(obj);
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbPropertyValues x = dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues();
int optimisticValue = x.GetValue<int>("OptimisticVersion");
```

Has anyone any idea why it can grab database values the first time and throw an exception on next calls ?

Here is the stack trace:

```
System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInComplexType(StateManagerMemberMetadata topLevelMember, StateManagerMemberMetadata complexMember, Object complexValue, Object oldComplexValue) 
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties) 
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.InternalGetOriginalValues(Boolean readOnly) 
at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.GetUpdatableOriginalValues() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.StateEntryAdapter.GetUpdatableOriginalValues() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.get_OriginalValues() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.GetDatabaseValues() 
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.GetDatabaseValues() 
at EORTC.BASE.DAL.EORTCBaseRep`1.Update(T obj) in     C:\Projects\_Prisma\EORTC.BASE.DAL\EORTCBaseRep.cs:line 121 
at EORTC.BASE.BLL.EORTCBaseManager`1.Update(T obj, Boolean validate) in C:\Projects\_Prisma\EORTC.BASE.BLL\EORTCBaseManager.cs:line 58 
at Prisma.BLL.ParticipatingServiceManager.Update(ParticipatingService obj, Boolean validate) in C:\Projects\_Prisma\Prisma.BLL\Managers\Service\ParticipatingServiceManager.cs:line 96 
at Prisma.Web.Controllers.ParticipatingServiceController.Edit(Int32 id, FormCollection collection) in C:\Projects\_Prisma\Prisma.Web\Controllers\Service\ParticipatingServiceController.cs:line 172 
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() 
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) 
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: could you point which exact line prompts the exception?

Comment: What is the call stack of the exception?

Comment: The exact line that prompts the exception is : System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbPropertyValues x = dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues(); Stack trace added

Comment: At this point `dbEntry` is definatly not null, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use Timestamps in your model and database table to track these values?

```
[Timestamp]
    public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

Comment: this is not an answer; you should use comments (when you will have enough reputation) for this

Comment: Yes, I am sorry about that, but I couldn't post comments before (I don't know why). I just tried to help

Comment: Yeah when we tried to use the OptimisticLock provided by EF, it wasn't able to create the database (without error). That's why we didn't use them (we weren't using migrations). But it is working now. Thanks.